# Excel 2010 Add-In having issues with saving picture clipboard to file

Tags: vb.net, excel

I'm trying to make an add in in vs2010 for Excel 2010 that copies an image to clipboard and then saves it.
The add in has a button which runs the following code:

```
       Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon.RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim app As Excel.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
    Dim desktopFolder As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
    Dim fileName As String = "D:\testaddin\test.jpg"
    Dim activeWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    'Dim currentCell As Excel.Range = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection
    Dim pic As Excel.Shape = activeWorksheet.Shapes.Item("Picture 1")
    pic.CopyPicture()
    If Not System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetDataObject() Is Nothing Then
        Dim oDataObj As IDataObject = System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.GetDataObject()
        If oDataObj.GetDataPresent(System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Bitmap) Then
            Dim oImgObj As System.Drawing.Image = oDataObj.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap, True)
            oImgObj.Save("d:\Test.jpeg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The code compiles just fine but when I press the button nothing happens.
One thing i know for sure is that the code DOES copy the picture to the clipboard as i checked that in mspaint.

How can I make the clipboard to be saved to jpeg?

Comment: Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Well it's this line: If oDataObj.GetDataPresent(System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Bitmap) Then    it never gets to save the file. Why is that?

Comment: `CopyPicture` has additional parameters - try specifying bitmap   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.copypicture.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2